# WordPress: Image width must not exceed 50px error

Tags: php, wordpress

In the WordPress backend, I was trying to upload a new image, but came across a `Image width must not exceed 50px` error.

I have not changed anything in the theme (i.e. in `functions.php`), but I did remove the caps in the `media settings`.

Here is a screenshot of my media settings:

[image]

They have been set to `0` so WordPress doesn't crop a `featured image` to thumbnail size.

I'm unsure where this `50px` cap, and the error in general, is coming from?

Here's a screenshot of my issue:

[image]

What is going on here?

Comment: Are you using any third-party plugin that related images?

Comment: @Bhautik - I am not, no. I have no image related or optimisation related plugins installed